# How to get last TTL from Traceroute?

Tags: linux, networking

Which is the easiest way to get the last TTL with traceroute? The last line with IP or Host....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
traceroute google.com | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

which just prints the number at the beginning of the last line which all things being equal should be the last TTL.

Answer (score 2):

The last host of a traceroute should be the destination. Any normal ping should give you that.

Alternatively, just look at the line number.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ traceroute google.com | awk 'END { print $1 }'
```